# How to find a list of the n closest coordinate on a graph

Tags: python, distance, min

Here is my problem, I have a masterlist and in it are sublists of data a string with telling the list's type, an x coordinate and a y coordinate.  How do I find the n-closest strings in the master_list using a key of the euclidian distance function   For example:

`my_location = ['a', .59, .59]
master_list = [['a', .5, .5], ['b', .3, .2], [a, .4, .4], ['b', .45, .45], ['a', .6, .6], ['b', .55, .55]]
input: function(3, my_location, master_list) 
output: [['a', .6, .6], ['b', .55, .55], ['a', .5, .5]]`

the key to the function should look like: key = sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2

Comment: where is n in you code?

Answer (score 2):

```
from math import sqrt

location = ['a', .59, .59]
master_list = [['a', .5, .5],
               ['b', .3, .2],
               ['a', .4, .4],
               ['b', .45, .45],
               ['a', .6, .6],
               ['b', .55, .55]]


def get_neighbours(distance, location, locations):
    neighbours = []    
    for loc in locations:
        if sqrt((location[1] - loc[1])**2 + (location[2] - loc[2])**2) < distance:
            neighbours.append(loc)
    return neighbours

print get_neighbours(3, location, master_list)
```

If you want to be fast you should look into the 2D collision detection stuff.. Axis Alligned Bounding Boxes, Quadtrees, Sweep and Prune etc..

You can do a quick test to eliminate far away nodes which is possibly worthwhile doing if you have a lot of nodes (otherwise keep the code simple and don't optimize prematurely):

```
if abs(location[1] - loc[1]) > d:
   continue

if abs(location[2] - loc[2]) > d:
   continue
```

If this is homework you're not doing yourself any favours getting others to do it for you :)